# Tcl_ParseExpr does not parse expression with 'dot' in it

Tags: c++, tcl

So I am trying to parse an expression using Tcl_ParseExpr:

```
    // Any syntax errors?
Tcl_Interp *myInterpBuild;
Tcl_Parse parseInfo;
std::string expression = "(test1==1) ? 0.0) : (test2.hello+1.0)";

if (Tcl_ParseExpr(myInterpBuild,expression.c_str(),-1,&parseInfo)
    == TCL_ERROR)
{
    std::string failMsg = Tcl_GetStringResult(myInterpBuild);
    std::cout << failMsg;
```

Now, usually this works and no error is give. However, if the expression contains a . (dot symbol) then it only parses the part of the expression up the the dot.

For example, if I set expression to '`(test1==1) ? 0.0) : (test2.hello+1.0)`' then only '`test2`' is parsed and '`hello`' is thrown away.

The output of the above is:

```
invalid bareword "test2"
```

It appears only to evaluate the expression up to and not including the dot character.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` character is *not* an operator in Tcl's expression language as things stand right now. It can be used within a floating point literal, of course, but it simply isn't a legal part of the grammar rules as an operator. Thus, Tcl's parser stops when it encounters it and throws an error: it would do exactly the same if you fed it into the Tcl `expr` command. What's more, Tcl's expression language doesn't currently support barewords *except* as function names (and there's a few keywords that look like barewords too, such as `true` and `false`).

Changing that would require rewriting the expression parser and (probably) assigning a meaning to that operator in terms of Tcl's internal bytecode. Not exactly a trivial thing (there's quite a few places in the code to change) but possible if you have a good idea for what to do. If you do, please talk to the Tcl Core Team and we'll see what we can do; you might find us quite receptive to a good suggestion!

Or you can use your own parser, of course. Absolutely nothing stopping that.

Comment: Unlike the main Tcl language, Tcl's expressions are described by a full grammar as they approximately mimic a subset of C expressions. But with more Tclishness.